# Calling Javascript function with multiple parameters from gridview hyperlink

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I am getting the following error when trying to call a javascript function from a hyperlink within a gridview.

JavaScript critical error in (unknown source location)

SCRIPT1006: Expected ')'

The alert in the function doesn't even show. Thanks in advance.

```
function EditResource(sResourceID, sTravelMName, sChronoMName) {
        alert("test");
        var options = {
            url: "http://192.168.9.12:1002/SitePages/ResourceEdit.aspx?ResourceID=" + sResourceID + "&TravelManagerName=" + sTravelMName+ "&ChronoManagerName=" +sChronoMName,
            title: "Edit Resource",
            autoSize: true,
            dialogReturnValueCallback: DialogCallback
        };
        SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);

    }
```

The hyperlink code

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" CssClass="padding5" ID="hpEdit" ToolTip="Set Manager" ImageUrl="../_layouts/15/images/Test/Icons/icon_edit.png"  NavigateUrl='<%# "javascript:EditResource(" + Eval("Resource_ID") + "," + Eval("Travel_Manager_Full_Name") + "," + Eval("Chrono_Manager_Full_Name")+")" %>'></asp:HyperLink>
```

Comment: What's the javascript function call look like in the actual HTML?

Comment: The call is in the code snippet of the hyperlink above. I'm calling it from the NavigateUrl property. Here is the actual html when the page is rendered href="javascript:EditResource(19,Joline Farquhar,Pikes)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to escape the string variables in your javascript call.

```
javascript:EditResource(19,'Joline Farquhar','Pikes')
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function invocation code has errors...

```
href="javascript:EditResource(19,Joline Farquhar,Pikes)"
```

notice the missing quotes around the name. It needs to look like this:

```
href="javascript:EditResource(19,'Joline Farquhar','Pikes')"
```